# how use Singleton object in different class loader....?

Tags: java, eclipse

in eclipse plugin i have two plug-in which are used there own class loader to load classes..  **2 main problem**
**Case 1:-**  in 1st Plugin i made a singleton class and when ever i want it to set some property form another plugin (because singleton so every object will change same object) but it can't do same as i accept.. because for every class loader there its own singleton object....
**Case 2:-**  in 1st or 2nd plugin i made a class with a single `static`property  and through another plugin i want to access that property...
i want to access that property but i can't because every class loader there own name-space that means there own static variable...
**what i did  is :-**
1. i make a class in 1st plugin with a `static String` variable
2. through 2ND plugin i set the value of that property
3. when i use it through 1st it how its value `null` and if through 2nd the is show that what  i set previously .
Now the problem is  how i can access those property...in case 1 and case 2

Comment: "because for every class loader there its own singleton object...." Are you saying that you load your same plugin multiple times on different class loaders? Because if all theses classloaders share the same "parent" classloader to get to your plugin then it should still be a singleton.

Comment: I am not loading same class multiple time i just want use my class  property in different plugin to but now it not .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Eclipse, each OSGi bundle (plugin) has its own classloader.  They are not hierarchical compared to other bundles.

But if you define a static variable in plugin1 and want to access it from plugin2, you would have plugin2 `Import-Package` or `Require-Bundle` by editing plugin2 **MANIFEST.MF**.  ex:, if this was plugin2's MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: %Plugin.name
Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.examples.propertysheet; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 3.2.200.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: org.eclipse.ui.examples.propertysheet.PropertySheetPlugin
Bundle-Vendor: %Plugin.providerName
Bundle-Localization: plugin
Require-Bundle: plugin1
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
Export-Package: org.eclipse.ui.examples.propertysheet
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: J2SE-1.4
```

`Import-Package` and `Require-Bundle` are the correct ways to see classes from one bundle in another bundle, as long as the bundles also use `Export-Package`

Comment: +1 And if you do that, the class in question (and its singleton field) will exist in just one place and be shared.

Comment: Please update your question with the 2 MANIFEST.MFs.  This works, you must be slightly mis-configured.