# How to access the public variable in plugin1 from plugin2 using OSGI framework

Tags: eclipse-plugin, osgi

I'm new to OSGI framework and I'm trying to access the 'Derived' Class variable 'publicVariable' from another class 'Derived2' like "Derived.publicVariable" but publicVariable is always shows null. I really appreciate if someone can help me out with this.
Thanks

Manifest file -  Derived2

```
Require-Bundle:com.xxxxxx.Derived1
```

Java code

```
    abstract class Base {
        protected Vector <String> supportedCommands = new Vector <String> ();

        protected abstract void initialiseCommands();
    }
    class Derived extends Base {
        private static Derived derivedPlugin =  null;

        public Derived()
        {
          derivedPlugin = this;
        }

        public static Derived getPlugin()
        {
          return derivedPlugin;
        }

        public String publicVariable = null;

        protected void initialiseCommands()
        {
            publicVariable = "someData";
            System.out.println("Derived" + publicVariable);
        }
    }


    class Derived2 extends Base {
            protected void initialiseCommands()
        {
            supportedCommands.add(Derived.getPlugin().publicVariable);
    System.out.println("IMRSAUtilitiesPlugin" +supportedCommands);
        }
```

Also referred below link, which is a similar issue but i'm not using any static variable, it is just a public variable.

[how use Singleton object in different class loader....?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8079362/how-use-singleton-object-in-different-class-loader/8079800#8079800)

Comment: Once you have added the `Require-Bundle` the rest is the same as a plain Java program.

Comment: This code won't compile. You reference the field `Derived.publicVariable` statically but it is not a static field. Please post the real code you are running, or the real error message.

Comment: Also: never use `Require-Bundle`.

Comment: @greg-449 But we can access directly with the name of the class by adding the class name in "Require-Bundle" and it doesn't need to be static class right ?

Comment: No, that only works for static. This is no different from ordinary Java.

Comment: `Require-Bundle` (and OSGi in general) does absolutely nothing to change the semantics of the Java language. You cannot access a non-static field in a static way.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the question will not compile. You are trying to access an instance field (`publicVariable` in class `Derived`) in a static way, i.e. `Derived.publicVariable`.

OSGi does not change the semantics of the Java language, and if you cannot even compile your code then OSGi will certainly not be able to run it.

Comment: Now i changed into static but the value in "supportedCommands" vector always shows null in debug mode but it shows value when  run it. Do you know why it is showing null in debug mode ?

Comment: Because you never call the line of code that sets it to non-null.